# Is it possible to dynamically create LWC from aura component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-component

We can't dynamically create LWC like aura does. We can embed LWC in aura, is it possible to dynamically create LWC using $A.createcomponent within aura component?

Comment: can you updated the answer, since accepted answer is outdated now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you want to "dynamically" create an LWC you actually have to dynamically create an Aura component that statically wraps the LWC component.

**UPDATE**

As can be seen in other answers here, there are some undocumented ways to work around this without using a bespoke Aura wrapper. Use with caution; being undocumented, this could stop working at any time.

Comment: There are several additional answers that are not accepted, which show how to accomplish this.

Comment: Seems like my answer has been superseded though using undocumented behaviour (at least I have not seen the approach officially documented anywhere).

Comment: I'll cheerfully withdraw it if you mention that there are  alternatives in the other answers - I only downvoted because google's preview brought up your answer (Not that google ever misleads anyone w/ those info boxes or anything).

Comment: Thanks!  I have also found the events don't work quite correctly w/ those - Custom dispatched events were failing to be properly handled in the aura controller.  The standard events were properly handled, though

Comment: @HungryBeagle what was the issue with event handlers? I remember that I was able to properly handle events from dynamically created components

Comment: @ytiq I was able to standard events, but the custom events that were raised by the LWC would not go to handlers I defined via attribute.  In this page, there is a createComponentController.js example that links in a handler.  When I tried to attach handlers to the custom events via the attribute object, it would not recognize them. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm   - I stepped through SF's code, and it didn't recognize the handler.  I used the same method to attach a custom handler to a standard event, and that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Seems we were wrong...
This code worked for me.
The trick was to set true 'exposed' property in js-meta.xml

**LWCContainerAction.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:LightningQuickAction, force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**LWCContainerActionHelper.cmp**

```
({
init : function(component) {
    const recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
    $A.createComponent(
        `c:lwcTest`, {recordId : recordId},
        function(lwcCmp, status, errorMessage) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = component.get("v.body");
                body.push(lwcCmp);
                component.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.error("Error: " + errorMessage);
            }
        }
      );
}
})
```

**lwcTest.html**

```
<template>
    test success
</template>
```

**lwcTest.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    **<isExposed>true</isExposed>**
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image]

I have developed Aura Component wrapper for LWC specific for Lighting Actions. So now you can call LWC from Lighting Action with additional benefits.

Repo: https://github.com/SAItm/LWCAction

Comment: Works in my case as well, but even with isExposed=false (api version 50.0). Now I'm wondering whether it is some undocumented side effect of createComponent method or we could actually rely on this behaviour to build prod ready app.

Comment: For a holy calm I would suggest using with isExposed=true.

Answer (score 1):

Currently creating LWC components dynamically that has exposed:false

I pass data from LWC via Messaging Channel in format

```
{
    name: "",
    action:  "",
    params: {};
}
```

Here is part of my helper method.

```
{
 createComponent: function(cmp, event) {

   const eventParams = event.getParams();

   if (eventParams.action !== 'open') {
     return;
   }

   const params = Object.assign({},
     eventParams.params,
     { 'aura:id': eventParams.id }
   );


   $A.createComponent(event.getParams().name,
     params,
     $A.getCallback(function(element, status, errorMessage) {
       try {
         if (status === "SUCCESS") {
           component.set('v.currentModal', element);
           const target = cmp.find('container');

           const body = target.get('v.body');

           body.push(element);
           target.set("v.body", body);
         }
       }
     }));
 }
}
```

I'm using this code to generate dynamic LWC modals

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148611)

Comment: ye, you're right I'll example with code in 1 min

Comment: update answer with the code

Comment: @identigral what to do with accepted outdated answer?

Comment: Downvote it and/or ask the original poster to unaccept it

Comment: Now this was brought to my attention I have updated my answer. I still haven't seen official documentation supporting this so would be cautious about using this in production.

Comment: Phil, hopefully we'll be able to have a short chat here) I don't use any undocumented functionality. In documentation it states that LWC doesn't have exposed api to create components dynamically. Aura on the other hand can create dynamic components and it doesn't care wether it's Aura or LWC. Because you can use LWC components in Aura. But depends on your use case how someone would utilize it. I used it to create modals dynamically to speed up page loads